# GetWindowRect() fails, but IsWindow() is not

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I am trying to get the size of an external window:

```
POINT point;

point.x = 100;
point.y = 100;

HWND hwnd = WindowFromPoint(point);

LPRECT pRect = {0};
bool ret1 = IsWindow(hwnd);
bool ret = GetWindowRect(hwnd, pRect);
```

The return value of IsWindow is true, but GetWindowRect fails with the following error:

> 1400: Invalid window handle

What can be wrong?

Comment: Who owns the window?  Perhaps you're being blocked by UIPI (User Interface Privilege Isolation)

Comment: The window at this position was the visual c++. And if it is blocked are there any solution for my problem? I would like to highlight the window at a position(draw a red line around it, but not on its hwnd).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not the window handle that's invalid, but the null pointer you're passing as the second parameter to `GetWindowRect()`.

```
LPRECT pRect = {0};
```

This simply defines a **pointer** to a `RECT` and initializes the pointer to 0. You need to provide an actual `RECT` structure, as in:

```
RECT rc = { 0 };
GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rc);
```

Comment: Hm. Okay, I will try it. Sometimes windows error messages are a bit confused.