# CLI/C++ How to get window handle?

Tags: c++-cli

I need to get the handle of another window.

Here is the code for it:

```
private: System::Void btn_find_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             array<Process^>^ ps = Process::GetProcessesByName("Notepad");
             IntPtr X = ps[0]->MainWindowHandle;
             LPRECT rect;
             if (GetWindowRect(static_cast<HWND>(X.ToPointer()), rect)){
                 DEBUGBOX->Text = "OK!";
             }
             else
             {
                 //DEBUGBOX is a text box
                 DEBUGBOX->Text = ps[0]->MainWindowTitle;

                 //the following code is from MSDN, it is used to
                 //show a message box about the error
                 //P.S. I have no idea why it has to be this complicated
                 LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
                 LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;
                 DWORD dw = GetLastError();
                 LPTSTR lpszFunction = TEXT("GetWindowRect");
                 FormatMessage(
                     FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
                     FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
                     FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
                     NULL,
                     dw,
                     MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
                     (LPTSTR)&lpMsgBuf,
                     0, NULL);
                 lpDisplayBuf = (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT,
                     (lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf) + lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpszFunction) + 40) * sizeof(TCHAR));
                 StringCchPrintf((LPTSTR)lpDisplayBuf,
                     LocalSize(lpDisplayBuf) / sizeof(TCHAR),
                     TEXT("%s failed with error %d: %s"),
                     lpszFunction, dw, lpMsgBuf);
                 using MessageBox = System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox;
                 MessageBox::Show(gcnew System::String((LPCTSTR)lpDisplayBuf));
                 LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
                 LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);
             }
}
```

Currently it can find the process which is "Notepad" without a problem, but `GetWindowRect` function will fail, and goes to the cumbersome error message handling code, giving me "error 1400: Invalid window handle".

I have done some searching but I cannot find why it does not work. I suspect the `static_cast` from `IntPtr` to `HWND`, the code is from internet but seems legit.

I need the handle for some later operations as well.

Comment: Okay I found the reason. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18566332/getwindowrect-fails-but-iswindow-is-not

Kudos to Windows error message!

Answer (score 2):

if u know the name of the title bar of the window then try `FindWindowA`

```
HWND handle;
handle=FindWindowA(NULL, "Calculator");
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: and if it working in the project with UNICODE characters??? What happens then? It is better use the MACRO FindWindow instead

Comment: yes, u can use FindWindow also `handle=FindWindowA(NULL, L"Calculator");`

Comment: Are you sure that handle=FindWindowA(NULL, L"Calculator");even compiles? The proper way, in my humble opinion, is  handle=FindWindowW(NULL, L"Calculator"); (using UNICODE) or  handle=FindWindowA(NULL, "Calculator");(using ANSI). Even better, use instead FindWindow macro to avoid know what character set is used in the project, so make your code "agnostic" to character set.

Comment: `handle=FindWindowA(NULL, L"Calculator");` and `handle=FindWindow(NULL, "Calculator");` both get complaints(incompatible types). And neither of them works for me.@BuCkETBoSS

Comment: @anetworknoobie u need to cast it as LPCWSTR (by appending the text with L) only when using `FindWindow()` try using `handle=FindWindow(NULL, L"Calculator");` and `handle=FindWindow(NULL,L"Calculator");`

Comment: @JTejedor yes, i just tried it again to confirm. Also the window that u are trying to get a handle to, must be running

Comment: `handle=FindWindow(NULL,L"Calculator");` does not work...still gives me the same error